# MySQL Query to MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, translate

I have the following MySQL Query:

```
SELECT date, time, custom_id, Number
FROM traffic t
WHERE CONCAT(date, " ", time) BETWEEN "01/06/2014 00:00" AND "01/10/2014 23:00"
AND Number = 
(SELECT MAX(CAST(Number as SIGNED)) FROM traffic WHERE t.date = date and t.custom_id = custom_id)
ORDER BY date, CAST(Number as SIGNED) DESC, custom_id
```

This is the SQLFiddle in MySQL (working): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e1248/3

How can I convert/translate it to MS SQL? SQLFiddle (not working): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e124/1

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are date and time separate columns? And unless date is in a proper DATE format, this won't work in MySQL either!

Comment: The query presumably doesn't work in MySQL because of the date time formats.  The `between` will not work when it crosses month boundaries.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e124/21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date, time, custom_id, Number
FROM traffic t
WHERE CONCAT(date, ' ', time) BETWEEN '01/06/2014 00:00' AND '01/10/2014 23:00'
AND Number = 
(SELECT MAX(CAST(Number as smallint)) FROM traffic WHERE t.date = date and t.custom_id = custom_id)
ORDER BY date, CAST(Number as smallint) DESC, custom_id
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Exact same result, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you, with the link to SQLFiddle is all more simple!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that SQL server doesn't like `"` to enclose strings, these will get treated as a column name removing these (and the `CAST`s) works:

```
SELECT date, time, custom_id, Number
FROM traffic t
WHERE CONCAT(date, ' ', time) BETWEEN '01/06/2014 00:00' AND '01/10/2014 23:00'
AND Number = 
(SELECT MAX(Number) FROM traffic WHERE t.date = date and t.custom_id = custom_id)
ORDER BY date, Number DESC, custom_id
```

Edit: Whoops, just noticed cast is needed. See the answer by @bdn02 for an example.

Comment: That's why I wasn't getting the result I was expecting. Thanks!